# jQuery Sortable on div refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table with jQuery sortable on the rows.  The table is in a div and each row represents a volunteer job.  Below is the sortable code.

```
function JobSort () {
    $(".su-jsort").sortable({
        items: "> tbody tr.su-jsortitem",
        handle: '.su-jsorthandle',
        update: function () {
            var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/app/volunteerschedule/jobsort/' + $(this).attr("data-purl"),
                data: { sectionorder: order },
                type: 'POST',
                traditional: true
            });
        }
    });
    $("#su-sections").disableSelection();
}
```

When a user clicks to add a new volunteer job row, an ajax calls replaces the div containing the table with the form.  When the user saves the form, it refreshes the div with the updated table.

Sortable works when the page loads but does not work after a new job is added.  I have tried sortable "refresh" and am considering hiding the table and appending the row via sortable.  Before I rework the code, is there away around this?

Comment: Odd that the `sortable('refresh')` method doesn't work. Have you tried the `sortable('destroy')` method followed by applying `sortable({...})` again on the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destroyed worked once it was put before the table being removed.